Some LaTeX symbols are not rendering in Chrome
For example, some symbols in this Physics SE answer are rendered as empty glyphs on my macOS machine when viewed in Chrome:

Firefox renders the page correctly. Is there a font pack that I should install?

Note: the broken inline symbol is $\mathcal N$, produced by $\mathcal N$. Also broken is an $\underbrace$.

duplicate of this question?
